# Asymptotic growth rate of $\sum_{n\leq x}{f(n)}$

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I would like to prove that if $f$ is a positive monotone decreasing function then there exists $c>0$ such that $$\sum_{n_{0}\leq n\leq x}{f(n)}=\int_{n_{0}}^{x}{f(t)\,dt}+c+O(f(x))$$
I already proved that $$\sum_{n_{0}\leq n\leq x}{f(n)}=\int_{n_{0}}^{x}{f(t)\,dt}+c+o(1)$$
but I don't know how to improve this bound.

Comment: What interpretation of $\sum_{n_0 \leq n \leq x}$ are you working with?

Comment: $\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $\sum_{y \leq n \leq x} f(n) = \int_{x}^y f(t) dt + O(|f(x)| +|f(y)|)$

Comment: But doing that you don't get the $c$. Also, if $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=0$ then you are saying that, for example, $\sum_{1}^{\infty}{f(n)}=\int_{1}^{\infty}{f(t)\,dt}$, which is clearly not always true.